# How to check if an IP is contained in a network with python?

Tags: python, inetaddress

How do I check whether an IP is contained in a network with python?

Eg:

```
# pseudo code
IP('10.40.0.1').contained_in(CDIR('10.40.0.0/24)) == True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Python 3.3+ [`ipaddress`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('10.40.0.1') in ipaddress.ip_network('10.40.0.0/24')
True
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('10.40.2.1') in ipaddress.ip_network('10.40.0.0/24')
False
```

There's also [`backport of ipaddress`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress).

### Using [`ipaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr)

```
>>> import ipaddr
>>> ipaddr.IPAddress('10.40.0.1') in ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.40.0.0/24')
True
>>> ipaddr.IPAddress('10.40.2.1') in ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.40.0.0/24')
False
```

Comment: cool, it's possible to do that with netaddr too. Wondering what's the difference between netaddr and ipaddr. Thank you!

Comment: @nemesisdesign, You can use `ipaddr.IPNetwork(..) in ipaddr.IPNetwork(..)`. Unfortunately `ipaddress.ip_network(..) in ipaddress.ip_network(..)` does not work.

Comment: @nemesisdesign, You can use `ipaddress.ip_interface(u'x.y.z.w/n') in ipaddress.ip_network(u'x.y.z.w/n')`. But I'm not sure it is correct way.

Answer (score 0):

- you can check if ip exist in network using [hek](https://pypi.org/project/hek/)

```
import hek

ip = "192.168.0.1" # targeted ip address

result = hek.ipstuff.checkip(ip) # checking if ip exist, It'll return True is exist and False if not.

if result == True:
    print("ip exist")
elif result == False:
    print("ip doesn't exist")
```